# Projeto utilizando SPRING MVC nao realiza CRUD no banco corretamente

Tags: java, mvc, jpa

Tenho um `Controller` com alguns métodos implementados que salvam, atualizam e removem meu objeto `pr` do tipo `professorRepository` no banco. Estou utilizando o *Spring boot* para esse projeto, então o *CRUD* está acontecendo através do *JPA Repository*.

Os *GET's* e *POST's* **parecem** funcionar corretamente, pois a aplicação roda e renderiza no *browser* os `path` passados nos `requestMapping` direitinho. Entretanto, estou tentando atualizar e remover o meu objeto e ele está sendo salvo para todos os `maps`, os três formulários do `path` para cadastrar, remover e atualizar **salvam o objeto no banco**.

Alguém tem uma noção? E (aproveitando), alguém conhece alguma boa aula/documentação sobre o *Jpa Repository* **em português**?

Segue meu código com imports omitidos:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/professor.html"})
public class ProfessorController {
    @Autowired
    ProfessorRepository pr;


    @GetMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView professorInicio(){
        ModelAndView form = new ModelAndView("/form.html");
        return form;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView cadastraProfessor(@RequestParam ("coord") String coord , @RequestParam ("username") String username, @RequestParam ("nome")String nome, @RequestParam("email")String email){
        Professor prof = new Professor();
        ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("/index.html");
        prof.setUsername(username);
        prof.setNome(nome);
        prof.setEmail(email);
        pr.save(prof);
        return index;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/updateProfessor.html"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView professorEdicao(){
        ModelAndView form = new ModelAndView("/form.html");
        return form;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/updateProfessor.html"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView editaProfessor(@RequestParam ("username") String username){
        ModelAndView pagSucesso = new ModelAndView("/pagSucesso.html");
        pr.findByUsername(username);
        Professor prof = new Professor();
        prof.setUsername(username);
        pr.save(prof);
        return pagSucesso;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = {"/removeProfessor.html"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView professorRemocao(){
        ModelAndView form = new ModelAndView("/form.html");
        return form;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = {"/removeProfessor.html"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView removeProfessor(@RequestParam String username){
        ModelAndView pagSucesso = new ModelAndView("/pagSucesso.html");
        pr.findByUsername(username);
        Professor prof = new Professor();
        pr.delete(prof);
        return pagSucesso;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode abrir o Devtools no Chrome com F12 e na aba Network vê qual a requisição que tá sendo feita pelo client.

Comment: Obrigada! Sua dica me fez olhar o Response e percebi que como estava testando com o mesma view para todos os métodos, essa view tinha uma action para o POST somente do cadastro.

Comment: De nada, e não esquece de marcar o Post como resolvido.

Comment: @IsaíasdeLimaCoelho, aqui no Stack Overflow não marcamos como resolvido. Escrevemos uma resposta e a marcamos como a resposta aceita.